# Can I use interior oil-based primer on window glazing?

Tags: windows, paint, oil-based-paint

I'm re-glazing some windows with DAP '33'.  The instructions call for an oil-based paint or oil-based primer. I have a can of Sherwin-Williams oil-based interior primer. Will this work over the glazing?

I've read that exterior oil primers are more flexible. Will this be concern for priming the glazing?

Comment: what is "window glazing"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would use it, presuming I'm going to top-coat it with exterior paint.  Of course, the very designation of the primer as "interior" means that the manufacturer did not INTEND for you to use it outdoors.  So you're taking a chance.

But I'd do it and not give it another thought.  What's the potential downside?  Probably something like "If it doesn't hold up, you'll have to repaint the glazing in a year or so..."  I can live with that.